# Function that finds a position of a substring s2 in s1

Tags: c, string, strstr

Here is the code:

```
int position(char *s1, char *s2) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; s1[i]; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++);
        if (!s2[j]) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    char word1[101], word2[101];
    int p;
    printf("Type two words: ");
    scanf("%s %s", word1, word2);
    p = position(word1, word2);
    if (p < 0) 
        printf("Word'%s' does not exists in the sentence '%s'.", word2, word1);
    else
        printf("Position of the word '%s' is %d.", word2, p);
    return 0;
}
```

How does the second for loop work?

Does the function return `i` if it detects the word, if so how?

Comment: Do you see what is returned in this statement if (!s2[j]) return i;? If you see then why are you asking  the question?!

Answer (score 2):

The loop `for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++);` has an empty body `;` which can also be written:

```
for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++) {
    /* empty */
}
```

or

```
for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++)
    continue;
```

It computes the length of the initial substring of `s2` that matches characters at offsets `i` and subsequent of `s1`. At the end of the loop, `j` is the number of matching characters up to but not including the null terminator.

It this initial substring is the full string `s2`, which can be tested by comparing `s2[j]` to the null terminator `'\0'`, we have a match at position `i`, hence `if (!s2[j]) return i;`

Note that this function returns `0` for an empty substring `s2`, except if `s1` is also empty, which is somewhat inconsistent. It should either return `0` in all cases:

```
int position(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++)
            continue;
        if (!s2[j]) return i;
        if (!s1[i]) return -1;
    }
}
```

Note also that this function may have undefined behavior if `s1` is longer than `INT_MAX`, which is possible on 64-bit systems where `int` has 32 bits and pointers and object sizes have 64 bits. It would be safer to change the `int` variable and return types to `ptrdiff_t` defined in `<stddef.h>`, albeit not full sufficient.

The standard function `strstr` does not have these shortcomings as it is defined as returning a pointer to the match:

```
char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Note however that in C, it returns a non `const` pointer even if passed a `const` pointer, potentially breaking `const` correctness.

Here is a simplistic implementation using the same algorithm:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0;; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++)
            continue;
        if (!s2[j]) return (char *)&s1[i];
        if (!s1[i]) return NULL;
    }
}
```

Good C libraries use more sophisticated algorithms, which I encourage you to search and study.

Comment: Many compilers give you a waning if the loop body is just a semicolon after the loop head - exactly because the reader and writer both can miss it, completely misunderstanding what the code does.

Comment: Intel added a special instruction to their processors that can compare up to 16 x 16 bytes in one instruction. I would love to know if any standard library uses it.

Comment: @gnasher729: such specialized instructions are not easy to use for generic problems such as `strstr`, but are useful for specialized tasks such as image and digital signal processing, AI and crypto algorithms.